# Inequality for $l^p$-norm

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I am having troubles to show that $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq\|x\|_{p}$ is true for all $x\in l^{p}$ with $1\leq p <\infty$.

I have only so far
\begin{equation}
\|x\|_{\infty}=\sup_{n \in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|,
\end{equation}
which is true because the supremum is included on the sum and every term is non-negative. My problem is to complete the full form of the $p$-norm $\|x\|_{p}=(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p)^{1/p}$ on the right hand side of the inequality. I have tried to use the Hölder's inequality like here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings but in my case is $q=\infty$. I really apreciate your answers.

Comment: Trivial: $|x_n|^{p} \leq \sum |x_k|^{p}$. Take $p-$th roots.

Comment: I get it now. Then is $\sum|x_k|^p$ an upper bound for the set $\{x_n|n \in\mathbb{N}\}$ and hence greater than $\|x\|_{\infty}$. Thank you very much!.

Comment: Sorry, the set would be correctly $\{|x_n||n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Answer (score 1):

For $\epsilon > 0$ let $n\in\mathbb N$ such that : $$\left\|x\right\|_\infty - \epsilon \le \left|x_n\right|$$

So $$\left(\left\|x\right\|_\infty - \epsilon\right)^p \le \left|x_n\right|^p \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left|x_k\right|^p = \left\|x\right\|_p^p.$$

Taking the $1/p$ exponent et $\epsilon \to 0$ you have your result.

Comment: +1: This also addresses one detail the proof in the OP missed; mainly that the supremum need not be attained by any term in the sequence.